# Failing rails test - ActionController::UnknownFormat:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actiondispatch

I'm currently writing tests for all my controllers and have run into an issue I cannot solve. For one of my controllers, every test works (show, index, new, edit, update) but for some reason my #create test cannot pass. Just to clarify: all the fixtures and other methods run and pass fine - something is wrong with my create method or test on that method.

From what I can gather - the error may have something to do with the `respond_to |format|` line, but cannot seem to solve it.

**Here's the test:**

```
  test "should create captable" do
    sign_in @user
    post company_captables_url(@company, @captable), params: { captable: { company_id: @captable.company_id, name: "The BEST captable", version: @captable.version } }
    assert_response :success
  end
```

**Here's the method from the controller:**

```
  def create
      @captable = @company.captables.new(captable_params)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @captable.save
          format.html { redirect_to [@company, @captable], notice: 'Captable was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @captable }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @captable.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
```

**Error when running this test:**

```
Error:
CaptablesControllerTest#test_should_create_captable:
ActionController::UnknownFormat: ActionController::UnknownFormat
    app/controllers/captables_controller.rb:24:in `create'
    test/controllers/captables_controller_test.rb:38:in `block in <class:CaptablesControllerTest>'


bin/rails test test/controllers/captables_controller_test.rb:36
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your controller, one can see it responds to both html and json.

However, in your test request, it's hitting the url without any format (see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers, there's no `.anything` at the generated urls or you'll find the `.:format` ending). So the controller does not know what to respond_to, throwing the Unknown Format error.

You essentially have a few options:

1) You can actually write the url and add an explicit format

2) You can try adding the format there with concatenation (ie: `post "#{company_captables_url(@company, @captable)}.json"`)

3) You can set your routes to have a default response format (ie: `resources :captables, defaults: { format: 'json' }`). https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults

Comment: Still getting an UnknownFormat error when I edit my post line to be: 

`post company_captables_url(@company, @captable), params: { captable: { company_id: @captable.company_id, name: "Great captable!", version: @captable.version } }, as: :json`

Wonder if its something with how my controller handles the response

Comment: It would be helpful to get more context on your controllers to be able to trace it. Can you provide a gist?

Something that's catching my eye is that you have a json request and an html render as a response. Also I'm not sure on what @captable is. But feels odd to send a create request when the object already exists.

Comment: Also, I am not too familiar with Minitest, but running it on RSpec, adding `as: :json` still results in an HTML request (`#<Mime::Type:0x0000000267e970 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"], @symbol=:html, @string="text/html">`)

Adding the ".json" to the request does change it into .json, however.